# How can i add feature to custom Layer in Dotspatial?

Tags: c#, gis, developer-tools, feature-selection, dotspatial

I need to add Feature type as point , line or polygon to custom layer that user select layer name in combo box.
At the moment , every Feature just insert in the last layer made

This is my code :

```
public void test(Coordinate coord,string ftype)
{

        foreach (var item in map1.Layers)
        {
            if (item.LegendText ==ftype)
            {
                int selectedIndex = map1.Layers.IndexOf(item);
                ((Legend)map1.Legend).ClearSelection();
                map1.Layers[selectedIndex].IsSelected = true;
                map1.Layers.SelectedLayer = map1.Layers[selectedIndex];
                map1.Legend.RefreshNodes();
                label1.Text = Convert.ToString(selectedIndex);
            }

        }
        DotSpatial.Topology.Point point = new DotSpatial.Topology.Point(coord);
        IFeatureSet ifs = new FeatureSet(FeatureType.Point);
        IFeature currentFeature = ifs.AddFeature(point);
        DotSpatial.Symbology.CharacterSymbol pcs = new DotSpatial.Symbology.CharacterSymbol('o', "Webdings", Color.Black, 32);
        DotSpatial.Symbology.PointCategory pc = new DotSpatial.Symbology.PointCategory(pcs);
        pc.Symbolizer.ScaleMode = ScaleMode.Simple;
        pointScheme.AddCategory(pc);
        mpl.Symbology = pointScheme;
        mpl.ApplyScheme(pointScheme);
        _tempLayer = mpl;
        map1.MapFrame.DrawingLayers.Add(mpl);
        map1.MapFrame.Invalidate();
        map1.Invalidate();
        pointID++;
        map1.FunctionMode = FunctionMode.None;

    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it 
We should to Change Mappointlayer

first found indexof layer
                    selectedIndex = map1.Layers.IndexOf(item);
then set it on map point layer

```
                mpl= (MapPointLayer)map1.Layers[selectedIndex];
```